# Obtain a new list from the difference of two lists of different dimensions

Tags: python, python-2.6

I am using Python 2.6.2 as it is installed together with Abaqus (and I am writing a script for it)

I have a problem doing differences between sets.
I have created three sets as shown here:

```
TOT_list = set(xrange(n_unitcells))                          
TOT_par = list(set(itertools.product(TOT_list, repeat = 2)))
```

which results

```
TOT_par = [(1, 3), (3, 0), (2, 1), (0, 3), (4, 0), (1, 2), (3, 3), (4, 4), (2, 2), (4, 1), (1, 1), (3, 2), (0, 0), (0, 4), (1, 4), (2, 3), (4, 2), (1, 0), (0, 1), (3, 1), (2, 4), (2, 0), (4, 3), (3, 4), (0, 2)]
```

and

```
POS_in = [0,0]                                               
POS_par = [[1,2],[2,3],[3,4]]
```

I need to obtain a new set extracting the second two sets (POS_in and POS_par) from the first one (TOT_par), ie something similar to:

```
TOT_new = list(set(TOT_par) - set(POS_in) - set(POS_par))
```

Obviously trying to use directly the difference between sets does not work.
I have tried to write some cycle, but I just got confused more...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You aren't casting to `set` deeply enough.

```
>>> POS_in = [0,0]
>>> set(POS_in)
{0}
```

`set(POS_par)` wouldn't work at all because it contains `list`s, an unhashable type.

To fix this, give each `list` a standard structure (a nested `list` like `POS_par` has would work well), turn each pair into a `tuple`, and then turn the `tuple`s' container into a `set`:

```
>>> POS_in = [[0,0]]
>>> POS_in_set = set(map(tuple, POS_in))
>>> POS_in_set
{(0, 0)}
>>> POS_par = [[1,2],[2,3],[3,4]]
>>> POS_par_set = set(map(tuple, POS_par))
>>> POS_par_set
{(1, 2), (2, 3), (3, 4)}
```

You can then do `TOT_new = list(set(TOT_par) - POS_in_set - POS_par_set)`.

Comment: Glad to hear it. You can mark this answer as having solved the issue by clicking "accept" below its score.